# "The request failed. The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send" during creation of calendar appointment using EWS

Tags: exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

Using: EWS 1.1, Exchange server 2010 SP1, VB.Net

I am using EWS to create calendar appointment for more than 2000 users in my company via windows service, I developed a windows service that will create or update appointments for users when they create or update their appointment in our own company enterprise application. I have a windows service installed and this service is started by a service account that has Impersonation rights on Exchange server 2010.  This service will call a DLL to create or update appointment in Exchange for users.

> 1. Initialize ExchangeService with version Exchange2010_SP1
> 2. UseDefaultCredentials=True (the logged in user has Impersonation rights)
> 3. Use ImpersonatedUserId to impersonate the user that I want to create calendar appointment
> 4. Initialize an Appointment object (appointment = new Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Appointment)
> 5. Populate the Appointment object with values (for example, the properties Start, End, IsAllDayEvent, Body, Sensitivity, Subject, Location)
> 6. Create the appointment with Appointment.Save(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, SendInvitationsMode.SendToNone)
> 7. When users update their appointment in our enterprise application, I use Appointment.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite, SendInvitationsOrCancellationsMode.SendToNone)

Here is some codes snippets:

```
Try
    'Initialize the Exchange service
    exchangeService = New ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1)
    impersonationContext = CType(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity, System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity).Impersonate

    exchangeService.UseDefaultCredentials = True
    exchangeService.ImpersonatedUserId = New ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, "user1@domain.com")

    System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = New System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AddressOf ValidateCertificate)

    exchangeService.Url = New Uri("https://server/ews/Exchange.asmx")

    'Create or Update appointment
    If newAppointment Then
        appointment = New Appointment(exchangeService)
    Else
        appointment = Appointment.Bind(exchangeService, New ItemId(appointmentId))
    End If

    With appointment
        .Subject = *subject*
        .Start = *start date*
        .End = *end date*
        .Body = *msgbody*
        .Location = *location*

        If newAppointment Then
            .Save(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, SendInvitationsMode.SendToNone)
        Else
            .Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite, SendInvitationsOrCancellationsMode.SendToNone)
        End If
    End With
Catch ex As Exception
    'Throw exception here
Finally
    If Not impersonationContext Is Nothing Then
        impersonationContext.Undo()
    End If
End Try
```

the impersonation there is because when this is called from the windows service, the current WindowsIdentity is the IIS AppPool, so I need to impersonate the service acccount before I can initialize the exchange service and create/update appointment.

There is new exchange service created each time there is a need to create or update appointment.

Most of the time the process went well, but sometimes I will get a ServiceRequestException that I do not know why and what causes it:

> Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestException: The request failed. The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.ObjectDisposedException: Safe handle has been closed at System.Security.Principal.Win32.ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(SafeTokenHandle hToken) at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.SafeImpersonate(SafeTokenHandle userToken, WindowsIdentity wi, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(StackCrawlMark& stackMark) at System.Security.SecurityContext.SetSecurityContext(SecurityContext sc, SecurityContext prevSecurityContext, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.SetExecutionContext(ExecutionContext executionContext) at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData) at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) at System.Net.ServerCertValidationCallback.Invoke(Object request, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) at System.Net.ServicePoint.HandshakeDoneProcedure.CertValidationCallback(String hostName, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.VerifyRemoteCertificate(RemoteCertValidationCallback remoteCertValidationCallback) at System.Net.Security.SslState.CompleteHandshake() at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive